# How to correctly put extended ASCII characters into a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to write some data in an array that contains extended ASCII characters to a CSV file. Below I made an small example of the code I'm using on real file.

The array `text_array` represents an array containing only one row.

```
import csv

text_array = [["Á","Â","Æ","Ç","Ö","×","Ø","Ù","Þ","ß","á","â","ã","ä","å","æ"]]

with open("/Files/out.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(text_array)
```

The output I'm getting on CSV file is wrong, showing these characters.

```
Ã   Ã‚  Ã†  Ã‡  Ã–  Ã—  Ã˜  Ã™  Ãž  ÃŸ  Ã¡  Ã¢  Ã£  Ã¤  Ã¥  Ã¦
```

I found that the code below fixes the issue in Python 3.4 but I'm working on Python 2.7.

```
c = csv.writer(open("Out.csv", 'w',  newline='', encoding='utf-8'))
```

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**
I receive some links as comments, but is a kind of difficult for me to understand what is needed to do to fix this issue. May someone show some example please.

Comment: There's example `UnicodeReader` and `UnicodeWriter` classes in the Python 2.x `csv` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) that might help.

Comment: @martineau you'll probably also need to put a BOM at the front of the file so that software like Excel will properly read the UTF-8.

Comment: @mark: Good point. Fortunately there's some [BOM constants](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.BOM) defined in the `codecs` module that ought to make doing that fairly easy.

Comment: Hello both. Thanks for answer. I'm new to Python and I don't understand what BOM is. Thanks for the link shared but is a kind difficult for me since there is no an example there. May you show some example in what I'd need to do please.